# Policystatement is getting generated while adding SNS destination to Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

I have a create-lambda stack and i am adding an existing SNS topic as the destination thru CDK + Python. While deploying the code i am getting an error `The function's execution role does not have permissions to call Publish on arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<accid><SNStopic>`

Here is my lambda event invoke config code:

```python
    cfn_event_invoke_config= _lambda.CfnEventInvokeConfig(
        self, "MyCfnEventInvokeConfig",
        function_name="lambda-gluetrigger",
        qualifier='$LATEST',
        destination_config=_lambda.CfnEventInvokeConfig.DestinationConfigProperty(
            on_success=_lambda.CfnEventInvokeConfig.OnSuccessProperty(
                destination=SNStopicARN
            )
        )
    )
```

Also, here is the code to add the IAM policy to the lambda execution role:

```python
   lambda_exec_role.attach_inline_policy(_iam.Policy(
        self,
        "sns-publish-policy",
        document=_iam.PolicyDocument(
            assign_sids= True,
            statements=[
                _iam.PolicyStatement(
                    effect=_iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                    actions=[
                        "sns:*"
                    ],
                    resources=["*"]
                )
            ]
        )
    )
    )
```

I tried granting access to SNSTopic's Arn in the resources, tried with `sns:publish` to `sns:*` but nothing has worked so far.
I also can not use [add_to_role_policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/Function.html) , since i don't have access to add anything additional to the role programmatically. Can somebody please help and tell me what am i missing?

Comment: Why are you using L1 Cfn constructs?

Comment: I first tried with L2 construct too.  `on_failure=destinations.SnsDestination(snstopicfailure),                                        on_success=destinations.SnsDestination(snstopicsuccess)`
But cdk is generating an IAM Inline policy behind the scenes and tries to add sns:publish to the lambda execution role, despite that role already has sns:publish.   And as i mentioned above, i do not have access to create a policy and attach it to a role.

Comment: But you do have access to add an inline policy? Are you sure that it works?

Comment: I have access to add the inline policy to the role, I can use role A to deploy anything under IAM. Anything outside of IAM , eg: Lambda, I have to use Role B for the deployment. I have already created and deployed the lambda execution role and added sns:publish using role A. Since, cdk is again generating an inline policy and i can use only Role B to deploy lambda stack, it fails because Role B cannot deploy anything under IAM. To me it looks like a CDK defect , CDK is generating by default an inline policy without seeing if the execution role already has the access to that resource or not.

Answer (score 0):

I should have done this earlier,nevertheless, we were able to find a solution for this scenario. We work in an ALZ account where access to create IAM and Policy is very restricted. Hence, the solution to the above situation is to use [mutable=false](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/README.html#using-existing-roles) property while importing the role into a stack.